# HTML- Contents of the page are overflowing

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I was making a dashboard where there is a sidebar on the left side. Whenever i want to put some contents on the page, some of it used to be behind said sidebar.I added `overflow-x:auto` and this happened
[image]
This is the code of the dashboard:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.sidenav {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <app-header></app-header>
  </div>
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="sidenav">
      <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I put `overflow-x:auto` in the 'container'. But when i remove it, something like this happens
[image]

What do I do?
Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: If you are using `position: absolute;` on `.sidenav` then there is no need to set `float` property. Just use `left: 0`;

Comment: @KunalTanwar Thanks, that worked. But the white spaces on the right still remains

Comment: Can you provide entire code??

Comment: @KunalTanwar I already put it in the post. That is the entire code

Comment: I mean the elements inside your `.content` also.

Comment: `
 <div class="container">
  <div class="top-row d-flex">
    <div class="food-items d-inline-flex ml-5">
      <app-food-items></app-food-items>
    </div>
    <div class="suggestions d-inline-flex ml-5">
      <app-new-suggestions></app-new-suggestions>
    </div>
    <div class="user-items d-inline-flex ml-5">
      <app-user-items></app-user-items>
    </div>
    <div class="rating d-inline-flex ml-5">
      <app-ratings></app-ratings>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I solved this issue.

This is what I did.
dashboard.html:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column h-100 w-100">
  <div>
    <app-header></app-header>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 h-100 w-100">
    <div>
      <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </div>
    <div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

dashboard.css

```
*{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```